# Angular: Bind newly loaded ".js" controller to newly loaded "html" view after bootstrap on ngRoutes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, partial-views

I'm new to Angular. I am loading **dynamic views with ngRoutes** (very cool), and I am loading their **respective .js controllers** to make it even more cool. But I'm having trouble **binding them** both since bootstrap already happened;

I have a view in "../partials/inicio.php" and its controller in "/assets/js/partials/inicio/inicio.js", neither is loaded before bootstrap. To load them when url tag is "/" I use the next method in main.js: (and **it loads them** without problems).

**main.js**

```
  app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when("/", {templateUrl: "../partials/inicio.php", 
            resolve:{
              load: function($q, $route, $rootScope) {

                var deferred = $q.defer();

                var dependencies = [
                  '/assets/js/partials/inicio/inicio.js'
                ];

                $script(dependencies, function () {
                  $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    deferred.resolve();
                    console.log("The promise has resolved.");
                  });
                });
                console.log("The promise was made.");
                return deferred.promise;
              }
            }
          })
```

**assets/js/partials/inicio/inicio.js**

```
  app.controller('inicio', function ($scope) {
     console.log("Controller responds from the INSIDE in inicio.js");
  });

  console.log("Controller responds from the OUTSIDE in inicio.js");
```

**../parcials/inicio.php**

```
 <script>console.log("View is loaded in inicio.php");</script>

 <div class="container" id="inicio" ng-controller="inicio">
 </div>
```

So, if you notice the **console.logs**, it renders them as follows:
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUOPX.png)

So both the view and controller are loaded in the "correct order" (first the controller and then the view). Obviously I get an error when the view is loaded because it does not find ng-controller "inicio".

**How can I bind them?** How do I "register" the controller after bootstrap and attach it to the view?

**Keeping in mind:**

- I do not want to preload the controller or its declaration.
- If I have to add modules or make references to dependencies(Eg. ControllerProvider) I need to know where and when they have to happen.

I appreciate this very much!

Comment: your question says "I do not want to preload the controller or its declaration."  what exactly is your reasoning behind this? You seem to be taking an unorthodox approach to a very common task, but it's not really clear from the code examples why you need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `controller` field inside the route config. After that you won't need to use `ng-controller` anywhere, because it will be automatically assigned to the template:

```
$routeProvider
  .when("/", {templateUrl: "../partials/inicio.php", 

        // assigning a controller to the view
        controller: 'inicio',

        resolve:{
          // loading dependencies
        }
      })
```

Then, use `ng-view` instead of `ng-controller`. This should be placed inside a main html file (`index.html` or `index.php`).

```
<div class="container" id="inicio" ng-view>
</div>
```

This should load the scripts firstly and then assign controller to the view. This way partials will be loaded into the div with `ng-view` directive when route changes.

**Edit**

If you ever need to have a controller which should be applied to all partial views (for example navbar controller in `index.html`), you can always add a `script` tag for this one controller. The rest can be loaded dynamically inside `resolve` in route config.

---

**Edit 2**

I've tried to further investigate the problem, but whatever I did, I had the same error as you. However, I can provide a solution with different scripts loading library which I used in one of the projects in the past: `ocLazyLoad` (https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs). I tested it and it works without any problems. What you need to do after adding ocLazyLoad to the project is:

*Step 1*

Add `'oc.lazyload'` module to the app module, e.g. `angular.module('app', ['oc.lazyload'])`

*Step 2*

Change the `resolve` part to:

```
//...

resolve:{
    load: function($ocLazyLoad) {
         var dependencies = [
              '/assets/js/partials/inicio/inicio.js'
         ];

         return $ocLazyLoad.load(dependencies);
}
//...
```

Comment: Thank you. I get a "inicio is not a function got undefined" error on the controller declaration: "... app.controller('inicio', function ($scope) { ..."

Comment: I tried to find the reason of the problem, but unfortunately i ended up with the same error as you. It is late here, so I gave up with `$script` library and provided a solution with different library which I used in the past. Check the **Edit 2** section for more details. If you however would like to stay with `$script` library, I cannot help with it right now. Maybe someone else does :-)